# c# insert header row into header table data into data table

Tags: c#, ssis

I am looking for help. Below is the code that I tried but am not getting data in header table, What wrong am I doing? Also, am getting an error "There is already an open DataReader associated with the Command which must be closed" at this line -  adp.Fill(HeaderColumns);

I want to insert the header row into this table: header table and other data into the other table: datatable

```
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string directoryname =  file.Directory>name;
    string filename = file.Name;

    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFolderPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\""; 
 
    OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    cnn.Opne();

    DataTable dtsheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
    {
        if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("xlnm"))
            sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    
        OleDbCommand con = new OleDbCommand("select *,'"+filename+"' as filename,'"+sheetname+"' as sheetname,'"+ "from [" +sheetname+"]", cnn);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(con);

        con.CommandTimeout = 0;
    
        using (OleDbDataReader headerreader =  con.ExecuteReader(CommandBehaviour.SchemaOnly))
        {
            DataTable HeaderColumns = new DataTable();

            List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
            adp.SelectCommand = con;
            adp.Fill(HeaderColumns);

            foreach(DataColumn colin HeaderColumns.Columns)
            {
                string columnName = HeaderColumn.[0][column.ColumnName].ToString();
                columnNames.Add(columnName);
            }
            using (SqlBulkCopy headbc = new SqlBulkCopy(myadoconn)
            {
                headbc.DestinationTableName = "HeaderTable";
                headbc.WriteToServer(headerreader);
                headbc.Close();
            }
        }

        using (OleDbDataReader datareader =  con.ExecuteReader())   
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy dbc = new SqlBulkCopy(myadoconn)         
            {   
                dbc.DestinationTableName = "DataTable";                           
                dbc.WriteToServer(datareader);              
                dbc.Close();        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform two operations simultaneously on the same connection.
You need to move:

```
DataTable HeaderColumns = new DataTable();
List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
adp.SelectCommand = con;
adp.Fill(HeaderColumns);
```

before line

```
using (OleDbDataReader headerreader =  con.ExecuteReader(CommandBehaviour.SchemaOnly))
```

Comment: I tried but HeaderTable table, am getting all rows I should get only 1 row (header columns as a row) in the HeaderTable table